# How to prevent from automatically adding whitespace character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem about SQL Server in my visual studio 2012 web site project. For example; I have a table named "user" that has columns "name" ( varchar(16) ) and "surname" ( varchar(16) ). I add new data such as name: "john" surname: "holiday", but SQL Server automatically fills the rest of the variable with whitespace character. It seems like [image]. How can I block this? I hope I explained my problem clearly.

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=MYPC-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=fff;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception s)
    {
        FailureText.Text = s.ToString();
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [person] WHERE user_name='" + UserName.Text + "' AND user_password='" + Password.Text + "' ", connection);

    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (this.CompareStrings(dr["user_name"].ToString(), UserName.Text) &&
            this.CompareStrings(dr["user_password"].ToString(), Password.Text))
        {
            FailureText.Text = "ok";
        }
        else
        {
            FailureText.Text = "no";
        }


    }
    connection.Close();
    dr.Close();
}
```

For example when I am debugging "dr["user_name"]" variable is like that in watch : [image]

Comment: This normally happens when the type is defined as `char(16)` in the database or at some point along the way.

Comment: Couple of questions:  How are you adding to the user table?  Second, is the [name] column also varchar?  It sounds like it's a char column, which space pads.

Comment: #Mate What do you mean exactly? I couldn't understand. It is not about code, I think there is a problem with MSSQL.
 #DWright I add manually from visual studio sql server explorer. Yes [name] column is varchar too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.CompareStrings(dr["user_name"].ToString(), UserName.Text)--> dr["user_name"].ToString().Trim()`

might solve your problem if anyway there are some extra whitespaces

Comment: Sorry, but I guess this is not a complete solution though

Answer (score 1):

You must have used the ANSI_PADDING setting when you created the table. If so, you'll need to drop and create the table again.

Comment: But http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx says "In a future version of Microsoft SQL Server ANSI_PADDING will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will produce an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."